# Modifying in place with a conditional using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

This is a "how do I do this base R thing in data.table" type question. My objective is to assigned a value to a column based on some condition. How I typically do this in base R is below. My question is how is this typically done in data.table:

```r
library(data.table)

iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Sepal.Width > 3] <- NA

irisDT <- as.data.table(iris)

irisDT$Sepal.Length[Sepal.Width > 3] <- NA
#> Error in irisDT$Sepal.Length[Sepal.Width > 3] <- NA: object 'Sepal.Width' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html   , section 2b

Comment: Yep that is 100% it. Thank you.

Comment: This is the answer: `irisDT[Sepal.Width > 3, Sepal.Length := NA]`. @DavidKlotz did you want to add that so I can accept?

Comment: in general, try and get used to doing everything inside `[]` with data.table. I sometimes think of `[` as letting you "step into" your data to do some processing before you "step out" with `]`

Comment: @MichaelChirico The part that I find a little hard to get used to is that `irisDT[Sepal.Width > 3, ]` will subset the data while the code above returns the same number of rows as the original data.

Comment: @boshek it might help to split your thinking into whether := is used... here, `i` is evaluated first & then those rows are available to j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [data.tables documentation](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html), specifically section 2b for modifying in place.

I would do:

```
irisDT[Sepal.Width > 3, Sepal.Length := NA_real_]
```